# C# System.Security.SecurityException Request for FileIOPermission Failed Error

Tags: c#

I wrote a C# program that takes 3 inputs and writes them to a text file on a server. The program runs fine on the XP computer but the Windows NT computer gives the following error:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed

Both are running the .exe file from the same server location and the Windows NT computer is able to open and save changes to the text file.

Comment: Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229070%28VS.80%29.aspx NT is not a supported platform for .NET 2.0.

Comment: Are you using the same account on both systems?

Comment: Joe: I was incorrect, it is running Windows 2000 Professional.

Al G: Yes, the I am using the same account on both systems.

Comment: Should the account have permission for IO operations if it has read write permissions?